# explode not working properly

Tags: php, string, explode

I have a csv file which I need to remove parts from, and it's 7017 lines long, so I'm using php to remove certain parts and put it back together, the relevant code for it is below.

```
$rows;
$count = 0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($files, 56000)) !== false) {
  $rows[$count] = $row;
  if (stristr($rows[$count][8], "Features:")) {
    $rows[$count][8] = str_replace("Features:", "features", $rows[$count][8]);
    $rows[$count][8] = str_replace(":", "", $rows[$count][8]);
    $rows[$count][8] = explode("features", $rows[$count][8]);
    if (isset($rows[$count][8][1])) {
      $rows[$count][8][1] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]);
      $rows[$count][8][1] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]);
      //$rows[$count][8][1] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]); produces error if  used
      $rows[$count][8][1] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][1][0]);
    } else if (isset($rows[$count][8][0])) {
      $rows[$count][8][0] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
      $rows[$count][8][0] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
      //$rows[$count][8][0] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]); produces error if  used
      $rows[$count][8][0] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][0][0]);
    } else {
      $rows[$count][8] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8]);
      $rows[$count][8] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8]);
      //$rows[$count][8] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8]); produces error if  used
      $rows[$count][8] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][0]);
    }
    $countif = 1;
    while (isset($rows[$count][8][1][0][$countif])) {
      $countif++;
    }
    $max = $countif - 2;
    $countif = 9;
    $counter = 1;
    while ($max <= 5 && $max >= 1 && $countif <= 13) {
      $rows[$count][$countif] = $rows[$count][8][1][0][$counter];
      $countif++;
      $counter++;
    }
    $rows[$count][8][0] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
    //$rows[$count][8] = $rows[$count][8][0][0];

  }
  $count++;
}

print_r($rows[14][8]);
```

The problem is that even though 'Compatible' is in the string refered to in the explode statement it remains as a single string, un-exploded so to speak. the output is as below.

> 100% Brand New Made from high quality material to ensure good quality
>   Prevent Scratches bumps grease and finger prints on the screen You can
>   now easily use the mobile or text people with the stylus Designed to
>   be used with your touch screen mobile **Compatible** with: Nokia : 5530
>   Xpress MusicPackage Contents: 1 x Stylus for Nokia 5530 Xpress Music -
>   White

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** the `var_dump($rows[14]);`

```
0 => string '41807' (length=5)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'http://images.esellerpro.com/2477/I/418/07/07_!B-dzTQ!BWk~$(KGrHqQOKnMEy1t9tWyLBM8tHiFEnQ~~0_1.JPG' (length=98)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
  6 => string '5055496500300    ' (length=17)
  7 => string 'STYLUS-5530-WHITE - STOCK CONTROL' (length=33)
  8 => string ' 100% Brand New Made from high quality material to ensure good quality Prevent Scratches bumps grease and finger prints on the screen You can now easily use the mobile or text people with the stylus Designed to be used with&nbsp;your touch screen mobile&nbsp;Compatible with:&nbsp;Nokia : 5530 Xpress MusicPackage Contents: 1&nbsp;x Stylus for Nokia 5530 Xpress Music -&nbsp;White&nbsp;' (length=386)
  9 => string '' (length=0)
  10 => string '' (length=0)
  11 => string '' (length=0)
  12 => string '' (length=0)
  13 => string '' (length=0)
  14 => string '-1' (length=2)
  15 => string '' (length=0)
  16 => string '' (length=0)
  17 => string 'Frooition' (length=9)
  18 => string '' (length=0)
```

**EDIT2:** Original Line:

```
3PREPAY-ZTEMF627W1GB        http://images.esellerpro.com/2477/I/217/94/03_!B8Zel8w!2k~$(KGrHqJ!hYEyrrVkKNYBM28dwn4o!~~0_1.JPG               5.0555E+12  ZTE MF627 THREE PAY BROADBAND USB MODEM WITH 1GB READY  New ZTE MF627 on Three Pay Broadband with 1GB allowance IncludedGet broadband speeds with no wires or hassles. Just plug this lightweight USB Modem into your laptop and watch as everything auto-installs whether you’re on Windows or Mac. Easy. The user friendly dashboard is also a breeze (so you don’t need any technical knowledge) and it lets you send and receive text messages while you’re online.The MF627 gives you download speeds of up to 3.6 Mbps. Plus you can use your new best friend as a memory stick just add a MicroSD card to the slot and load up to 4GB. And don’t ever worry about losing the lid because it’s connected with a handy strap! Compatible with: Most Desktops and Laptops (Also supports Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6)Packing Contents:1 X Brand New ZTE MF627 USB Model on Three Pay as you go Broadband  - 1GB Allowance Included Maximum 1 per customer please.                       -1          Frooition
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($rows[$count])` so we can see what the structure is. You've got far too much rewriting/overwriting/replacing going on to trace it in heads.

Comment: that's the entire content of the field I'm trying to split, everything else works perfect. even the `explode()` statement further up with 'features', but I'll edit to show you anyway.

Comment: Can you show me a line of sample text from the CSV file? I think your complicating the data structure, by using multi-dimensional indices.

Comment: there's the line in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem..

Its your second explode...

```
$rows[$count][8][0] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
```

If the line doesn't contain Features then $count[8] isn't exploded and tunred into an array. In your var_dump $rows[$count][8] is just a string and $rows[$count][8][0] doesn't exist. Change the line to do this..

```
$rows[$count][8] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8]);
```

But you might want ot consider putting that in an else statement instead of changing it. Because the what you'll have now will work IF the string contains Features and is exploded. So the line I'm suggesting should go in an Else statement incase Features isn't apart of the string and $rows[$count][8] is never exploded.

```
$rows;
$count = 0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($files, 56000)) !== false) {
  $rows[$count] = $row;
  if (stristr($rows[$count][8], "Features:")) {
    $rows[$count][8] = str_replace("Features:", "features", $rows[$count][8]);
    $rows[$count][8] = str_replace(":", "", $rows[$count][8]);
    $rows[$count][8] = explode("features", $rows[$count][8]);
    if (isset($rows[$count][8][1])) {
      $rows[$count][8][1] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]);
      $rows[$count][8][1] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]);
      //$rows[$count][8][1] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]); produces error if  used
      $rows[$count][8][1][0] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][1][0]);
    } else if (isset($rows[$count][8][0])) {
      $rows[$count][8][0] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
      $rows[$count][8][0] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
      //$rows[$count][8][0] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]); produces error if  used
      $rows[$count][8][0][0] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][0][0]);
    } else {
      $rows[$count][8] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8]);
      $rows[$count][8] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8]);
      //$rows[$count][8] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8]); produces error if  used
      $rows[$count][8] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][0]);
    }
    $countif = 1;
    while (isset($rows[$count][8][1][0][$countif])) {
      $countif++;
    }
    $max = $countif - 2;
    $countif = 9;
    $counter = 1;
    while ($max <= 5 && $max >= 1 && $countif <= 13) {
      $rows[$count][$countif] = $rows[$count][8][1][0][$counter];
      $countif++;
      $counter++;
    }
    $rows[$count][8][0] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8][0]);
    //$rows[$count][8] = $rows[$count][8][0][0];

  }
  else // THE STRING DOESN'T CONTAIN "Features"
  {
        $rows[$count][8] = explode("Compatible", $rows[$count][8]);
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on doesn't work? What changes did you make specifically? Did you put it in an else statement? Because right now for your example the entire IF statement doesn't run. All that happens is $count++ executes and the while continues.

Comment: You haven't done what i suggested. I may have poorly explained it. Your string does NOT contain "Features".. that means the if statement that is right after your first WHILE does NOT run. Meaning anything inside of it is not executed. No explodes will happen because they are inside that if statement. Follow me?

Comment: I've illustrated my meaning in my answer.

Comment: just copied and pasted, still no difference, though that's why there's `isset()` so if `$rows[$count][8]` isn't split, `isset()` would return 'false' for `$rows[$count][8][0]` and `$rows[$count][8][1]` and would execute the final else statement of splitting `$rows[$count][8]`

Comment: The isset never runs. None of the code inside the IF statment runs, do you understand that?

Comment: ah yes, I see. But it still doesn't work, as I copied and pasted the code, ran it, and still the same output :/

Comment: Print out $row[14][8], $rows[14][8][0] and $rows[14][8][1] and post the results for me.

Comment: ah, nevermind, left a bit of the old code :/ gave an error about passing an array through the string split.

Comment: Cool deal, glad we could get it figured out.

Comment: No problem. I get so deep in my own code that I don't see the little things ALL the time. Sometimes a new set of eyes are required that catch the little assumptions we all make when coding.

Comment: tell me about it, I'm the ONLY developer at the company I'm working at, and no one else know the languages.

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like what I think, you don't check if there is 'compatible' in the string. What about:

```
if (stristr($rows[$count][8], "Features:")) {
  $rows[$count][8] = str_replace("Features:", "features", $rows[$count][8]);
  $rows[$count][8] = str_replace(":", "", $rows[$count][8]);
  $rows[$count][8] = explode("features", $rows[$count][8]);
} elseif (stristr($rows[$count][8], "Compatible:")) {
  $rows[$count][8][1] = str_replace("Compatible", "compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]);
  $rows[$count][8][1] = explode("compatible", $rows[$count][8][1]);
  $rows[$count][8][1][0] = explode("-", $rows[$count][8][1][0]);
...
```

Comment: if you look at the output you can see there is 'Compatible' in the string, btw no need for the if statement to include 'features', that's removed with no problem.